# how to rearrange the ports of a simulink subsystem

Tags: simulink, subsystem

i implement a network simulation in Simulink/SimEvents (2018b) containing a Ethernet bus, which consists of three different subsystems like shown in the figure.

[image: Ethernet Bus in Simulink]

The blocks send entities to each other. This results to a quite complex scene, i'd like to improve by changing the position of the ports (like input port and output port on the same side of the subsystem). I haven't found a way how to do it.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.  Inports and Outports are always positioned on opposite sides of the block, and cannot be changed.

The exceptions are trigger and/or enable ports, which appear on a side which doesn't have inports or outports - but they can't be changed either.

In early versions of SimEvents you could position inports and outports on the same side, however I believe that functionality was removed in about R2017a or thereabouts.

In your case you could rotate your Node block to tidy up those connections, but there's nothing you can really do with the other signals crossing each other.  (You could use `GoTo` and `From` blocks, although I'm not a fan of doing that.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, then i have to accept it. I want to avoid `GoTo` and `From` blocks, because in a larger network it has no positive effects.